# Awaiting an event to complete before it gets fired again

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following scenario, I have an event that keeps on receiving xml's that need to be pushed into DB, the pushing code and event looks something like below :

```
async void signalrClient_OnXMLReceived(object value, MessageResponseEventArgs e)
{
    await SaveXML();
}

async task SaveXML(string xmlDoc)    
{    
    await SaveCustomer(GetCustomerDataFrmXML(xmlDoc));
    await SavePlantInfo(GetPlantDataFrmXML(xmlDoc))

   if(NotJobexists(GetJob(xmlDoc))
   {
    await SaveJob(GetJobInfo(xmlDoc))
   }
}
```

The problem is as soon as I encounter the first await in the save method, the control is taken back to the event where it receives new xml and calls save again, so My question is , how do I make sure that I execute all the code in the save method before the event gets fired again.

I do not have control over the event when it gets called, but  as and when it calls I want to make sure that I handle the event fully before it gets called next time, how can I do it?

UPDATE : Thanks all for your reply, The reason why I wanted to handle the event fully before it gets fired again is, if I get one more xml which is similar to the first one in the event, I was actually inserting both which will cause the duplicate entries in DB due to the async nature, finally I reordered my saves and checked if duplicate exists before couple of await save methods. This fixed the issue. I didn't tried the queue or Recative framework suggestions as this needed to be fixed quickly.

Comment: I can't see how it has to be async if what you need is a synchronous step by step execution...

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I do want async for the entire save functionality (it calls many other async methods) , but I want a synchronous event, meaning, I want the Method that event calls fully complete before the event get raised again.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

"..I want to make sure that I handle th event fully before it gets called next time, how can I do it?"

Don't make async the method at all should meet your requirement.

Comment: @David `async` tasks are little bit different than a thread pool call. In this case IMO there is really no reason to use `async`. Thread pool calls, a synchronized collection with a consumer/producer pattern (like new parallel collections) seem to fit better what he is trying to do (unless he is using `async` for another reason we can't see because outside that snippet). `async` is _viral_ and to use it just because it's "new" will force you to put `await` everywhere (unless you change - a lot - your logic too)

Comment: @user3432852 I mean: even if `Save()` itself has to be `async`...does each method need to be `async`? Does make sense to make them synchronous and to have just one `async Task Save()` method? What do they do? They really can work in parallel (DBs and I/O may don't increase performance with parallel requests). I feel I wouldn't guess because I can't imagine outer design. BTW you may even need just a simple `lock` inside your `SaveXML()` method (requests will be queued using thread pool, not very efficient if queue may be long but for simple cases it'll work).

Comment: In my realsave method there are so many other async save methods are present, I can see that syncronous call will really solve this issue, but then I have to remove the async from many method which I want consider as the last option, I wanted to know ,like in methods, when If we call a method with await, it can wait until the execution of that gets completed, I wanted to know if there is any way If I can await the event and its method execution before the event gets called again.

Comment: @user3432852 it depends how event is generated. If it comes from another thread then you need a lock (or a queue as Tigran suggested). Await will block thread where even is generated but if each event lives in different threads then calls will overlap. Try with a lock, if that's the issue then you can start to consider to use something else (your own queue or something from framework).

Comment: @Adriano, Thanks, I will try with a lock , I am also considering removing asyncs for the inner save methods. Looks like that would solve this permanently, I will update the progress soon. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need a [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.collections.queue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the event handler, where you push `XML` that arrives, and you need a timer, where on every tick you get an element from that queue and save it to `DB`.

Considering that [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.collections.queue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is FIFO structure, you will also maintain *an order* of the arrived `XML`s, in case it's important to you.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's Reactive Framework would handle this nicely for you.

Instead of handling events in the normal way you create an observable from the event:

```
var xmlreceiveds =
    Observable.FromEventPattern<EventHandler<MessageResponseEventArgs>>(
        h => signalrClient.OnXMLReceived += h, 
        h => signalrClient.OnXMLReceived -= h);
```

You can now get a steady stream of events that are guaranteed to complete before the next event comes.

You handle then like this:

```
var xmlreceiveds =
    Observable
        .FromEventPattern<EventHandler<MessageResponseEventArgs>>(
            h => signalrClient.OnXMLReceived += h, 
            h => signalrClient.OnXMLReceived -= h);

xmlreceiveds.Subscribe(ep =>
{
    SaveCustomer(GetCustomerDataFrmXML(ep.EventArgs.XmlDoc));
    SavePlantInfo(GetPlantDataFrmXML(ep.EventArgs.XmlDoc));

    if (NotJobexists(GetJob(ep.EventArgs.XmlDoc)))
    {
        SaveJob(GetJobInfo(ep.EventArgs.XmlDoc));
    }
});
```

You can easily make this be handled on a different thread by including an `ObserveOn` method call, like so:

```
var xmlreceiveds =
    Observable
        .FromEventPattern<EventHandler<MessageResponseEventArgs>>(
            h => signalrClient.OnXMLReceived += h, 
            h => signalrClient.OnXMLReceived -= h)
        .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default);
```

Comment: Use NuGet to find "Rx-Main". That'll make it easier to get the code working.